# Regex capture groups for "timer" sentence pattern

Tags: regex, ruby, capture-group

I am trying to write a regular expression that will allow me to parse and modify strings that may include an instruction to time a specific action, using capture groups to identify "hour" "minute" and "second" values in the input string.

In ruby I have a regex that gets close to the matches & capture groups I need

```
(?<hour_digit>\d+\s)[a-z]*\s?hour[s\b|b\s]|(?<minute_digit>\d+\s)[a-z]*\s?minute[s\b|b\s][a-z]*|(?<second_digit>\d+\s)[a-z]*\s?second[s\b|b]
```

I want to find an expression that can capture strings where multiple values could be matched, instead of independently; "5 hours and 15 minutes" should be one match & "30 minutes up to 1 hour" should be one match.
Visually the matching of the current regex is like so:
[image]

Comment: Does https://regex101.com/r/NeGzGB/1 help?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, that is helpful! This is a very powerful tool, thanks for sharing. Almost there, but that regex seems to match on punctuation marks. If the string had multiple sentences; "For the first step, wash the clothes for 15 minutes. While the clothes are washing, hold your breath for up to 5 minutes." could I ignore matching the commas & periods somehow?

Comment: Right, we need word boundaries. Shall I post an answer with https://regex101.com/r/NeGzGB/2?

Comment: Yes, that should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```rb
(?<!\w)\b(?:(?<hour_digit>\d+)(?:\s*(?:more|another))?\s*hours?)?(?:(?:\s*(?:or|up to|and|to))*\s*(?<minute_digit>\d+)(?:\s*(?:more|another))?\s*minutes?)?(?:(?:\s*(?:or|up to|and|to))*\s*(?<second_digit>\d+)(?:\s*(?:more|another))?\s*seconds?)?\b(?!\w)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NeGzGB/3). *Details*:

- `(?<!\w)\b` - a left-hand side word boundary (`[[:<:]]` or `\<` or `\m` in some flavors does this)
- `(?:(?<hour_digit>\d+)(?:\s*(?:more|another))?\s*hours?)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `(?<hour_digit>\d+)` - Group "hour_digit": one or more digits
  - `(?:\s*(?:more|another))?` - an optional occurrence of zero or more whitespaces and then `more` or `another` word
  - `\s*hours?` - zero or more whitespaces, `hour` or `hours`
- `(?:(?:\s*(?:or|up to|and|to))*\s*(?<minute_digit>\d+)(?:\s*(?:more|another))?\s*minutes?)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `(?:\s*(?:or|up to|and|to))*` - zero or more occurrences of zero or more whitespaces followed with `or`, `up`, `up to`, `and` words
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?<minute_digit>\d+)` - Group "minute_digit": one or more digits
  - `(?:\s*(?:more|another))?` - an optional occurrence of zero or more whitespaces and then `more` or `another` word
  - `\s*minutes?` - zero or more whitespaces, `minute` or `minutes`
- `(?:(?:\s*(?:or|up to|and|to))*(?<second_digit>\d+)(?:\s*(?:more|another))?\s*seconds?)?`- an optional occurrence of

  - `(?:\s*(?:or|up to|and|to))*` - zero or more occurrences of zero or more whitespaces followed with `or`, `up`, `up to`, `and` words
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?<second_digit>\d+)` - Group "second_digit": one or more digits
  - `(?:\s*(?:more|another))?` - an optional occurrence of zero or more whitespaces and then `more` or `another` word
  - `\s*seconds?` - zero or more whitespaces, `second` or `seconds`
- `\b(?!\w)` - a right-hand side word boundary (in some other regex flavors, it is `\M`, `\>` or `[[:>:]]`).